# how to permanantly install arduino ide 1.6.5?

Tags: software-installation, arduino

I downloaded the zip file `arduino-nightly-linux32.tar.xz` from [here](https://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) to my desktop.(YOU MAY NEED 64-bit. Ask your computer what it is: 32-bit or 64-bit):

I double clicked the `arduino-nightly-linux.tar.xz` icon and it opened a window that showed the `.tar.xz file`. I clicked the the extract button at the top of the window and extracted the contents of the `arduino-nightly-linux.tar.xz` archive to my desktop.

Once it was extracted, I could see and open the folder on my desktop (with all my other stuff), but could not run Arduino from there. I opened a terminal (Crtl+Alt+T)...

Note: capitalization matters in the terminal and depends on what YOUR machine calls the files/locations you are using...

I typed: `cd Desktop` and it gave me this prompt: `jay@jay:~/Desktop$`

I Typed on the line after the `$ ls --` I click Enter and it LISTED every file and folder on my desktop.

I could see Arduino-nightly in the list (it was blue for some reason). If you DON'T see it in the list, you are in the WRONG directory and you need to "cd" to the directory it IS IN.

then I typed on the line after Desktop$ `cd Arduino-nightly` and it gave me this:

`jay@jay:~/Desktop/arduino-nightly$`

after the $ on that line, I typed `./arduino`

but after doing steps mentioned above I programmed my `arduino` once after that I closed the application and now I cannot find it. each time when I want to open the arduino application I have to give command in terminal. how to permanantly install it?

Comment: what do  you mean by "permanent"?

Comment: because each time i close the application it completely vanishes from my pc. then again in terminal i have to run `.arduino/` command

Comment: your system 64 or 32 bit? application never vanish from system unless you remove or that application corrupt ! `./arduino` used to run the application

Comment: 64 bit           ohh  then what should i do? each time i want to run this application i have to run this command?? is there any alternate option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just install from the repositories?

```
sudo apt-get install arduino
```

Otherwise download the package, then in the directory of the download:

```
tar -xf arduino-1.6.5-r5-linux64.tar.xz
cd arduino-1.6.5-r5/
./arduino
```

To install it permamently (sort of) copy the contents of "arduino-1.6.5-r5" directory to somewhere (maybe $HOME/arduino") and  then copy the arduino.desktop file into $HOME/.local/share/application, edit it to contain the right pathes and you have it installed for your user "permanently".

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
# set variables for download
URL=https://www.arduino.cc/download.php?f=/arduino-nightly-linux64.tar.xz
DOWNLOAD="$HOME/Downloads/arduino-nightly.tar.xz"

# download file via wget from $URL to $DOWNLOAD
wget "$URL" -O "$DOWNLOAD"

# extract file to $HOME directory
tar xf "$DOWNLOAD" -C "$HOME"
# use sed to modify the provided arduino.desktop 
# file and redirect the result into $HOME/.local.share/applications
# to be able to start from dash
# sed's replace command s/searchpattern/replacepattern/
# the slashes are replaced by '#' to not need to escape slashes in path
# replace placeholder "FULL_PATH" with install directory 
sed "s#FULL_PATH#$HOME/arduino-nightly#" "$HOME/arduino-nightly/arduino.desktop" >"$HOME/.local/share/applications/arduino.desktop"
```

The script downloads the latest nightly build (website states hourly), extracts it to $HOME/arduino-nightly (that folder is in the tar, so I just used that) and copies the desktop file while modifying it. After logoff and logon you should be able to start it via the dash normally.

Comment: this gives me 1.0.something i want the latest version

Comment: how to install any software permanantly USING terminal? please help ASAP

Comment: thanks,  i really appreciate your help. script will help me lot as i am new user to this system

Comment: @BeowulfoF he can't because he is new user with reputation 1

Comment: @mayuri you get reputation if you question is upvoted or if your answers to other questions get upvoted. So be active ;-)

Comment: sir , what is  "$INSTDIR"

Comment: sorry, $INSTDIR was a variable, that I forgot to remove. I updated the script here already.

Comment: i am getting really confused what is #$HOME$#

Comment: You are asking about bash scripting fundamentals. It is nice, that you're interested, but here is not the place for it. I added some comments though.

Comment: @mayurikulkarni , those are pre-defined environment variables. Open a terminal then try these two commands `env` and `echo $HOME`. you gonna get the idea.

Comment: With `sudo apt-get` I get a version which does not allow to add Boards Manager URL. Using the official `tar.xz` file works perfect !